# is there a way that i don't have to write a full query in each condition?

Tags: php, sql

is there a way that i don't have to write a full query in each condition?

```
if($_GET['l'] == 1){
    $num = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM text WHERE type = '' AND gg = '1'") -> num_rows;
} 
elseif($_GET['l'] == 2){
    $num = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM text WHERE type = '' AND gg = '2'") -> num_rows;
} 
else {
    $num = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM text WHERE type = ''") -> num_rows;
}
```

Comment: Why cant you just create $num variable outside of if and then assign $num="SELECT......FROM text " and then inside each condition you can specify $num.="WHERE type=' '......and similarly for others. Is that ok for you ?

Comment: I recomend you to use classes or functions! Otherwise you will need to write same codes in each page again and again when you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Simple,
Declare a variable and make a query in the variable.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM text WHERE type = ''";
if($_GET['l'] == 1){
    $query .= "  AND gg = '1'";
} 
elseif($_GET['l'] == 2){
    $query .= "  AND gg = '2'";
} 
else {
    $query .= " ";
}
    $num = $db -> query($query) -> num_rows;
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: You could've also used a var instead of 1 or 2

Comment: ... or even better a look up array

Comment: it's not required last else condition.